# Copy scp multiple files from one server to another using snakemake

Tags: scp, snakemake

I would like to copy in parallel multiple number of files from one server to another. Is it possible to do it with snakemake? If not which are the alternatives?
This is my try. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx stands for IP of the server2. For now I get permission error.

```
workdir: "/path/on/server2/"

SAMPLES=["BOB","STEVE","JOHN"]
print (SAMPLES)

rule all:
    input: 
        expand("/path/on/server1/{sample}", sample=SAMPLES)

rule rename:
    input:
        "/path/on/server2/{sample}"
    output:
        "/path/on/server1/{sample}"
    shell:
        """
        scp -i /path/to/private_key.txt -r ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:{input} {output}
        """
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use snakemake.  For your example you will want to remove the input directive pointing to the second server since snakemake won't be able to verify it exists prior to starting.

As for alternatives, you can search as well as I can, but I'd venture to guess rsync will come up often along with some xargs piping.

One argument *for* using snakemake is if the outputs were temporary, then you could limit intermediate files and automatically clean up the working copies.  I'd also recommend setting a custom resource for this rule to limit how many jobs of this type are run simultaneously.  Your bottleneck will be network communication over multiple threads.